# Query to get data for past X months in JPQL

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jpql

I have constructed following JPQL query where result is being sent based on the timestamp being passed in. 
I am looking to modify this and pass in a number instead which is the month value and get all results from past 6 months for example.

I am using Oracle DB if that is relevant. I tried passing in datediff method in this query but it is throwing compilation errors.
Is there a way to do this?

My current query.

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(urlCount.referEventTotalCount) " +
            "FROM UrlCountEntity urlCount " +
            "JOIN urlCount.eventTypes et " +
            "WHERE urlCount.url.urlTx IN :urls " +
            "AND et.referEventTypeDs =:eventType " +
            "AND urlCount.updateTimeStamp <=:timeStamp") 
    Integer getTotalCount(@Param("urls") List<String> urls, @Param("eventType")String eventType, @Param("timeStamp")Timestamp timeStamp);
```

Looking to modify the line -> "AND urlCount.updateTimeStamp <=:timeStamp")

```
  @Query("SELECT SUM(urlCount.referEventTotalCount) " +
            "FROM UrlCountEntity urlCount " +
            "JOIN urlCount.eventTypes et " +
            "WHERE urlCount.url.urlTx IN :urls " +
            "AND et.referEventTypeDs =:eventType ")
            // "AND urlCount.updateTimeStamp <=:timeStamp") // instead of this, pass in the numOfMths value to calculate how much data to show (example past 3 mths)
  Integer getTotalCount(@Param("urls") List<String> urls, @Param("eventType")String eventType, @Param("numOfMths")int numOfMths);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply modify the query to select anything *after* a particular timestamp threshold and then pass in whatever timestamp corresponds to "6 months ago" at the current time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Oracle you can use ADD_MONTH with a negativ value to subtract.

```
ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6)
```

You can call this functions like this:

```
function('ADD_MONTH', CURRENT_DATE, -6)
```

So your query could look like this:

```
 @Query("SELECT SUM(urlCount.referEventTotalCount) " +
        "FROM UrlCountEntity urlCount " +
        "JOIN urlCount.eventTypes et " +
        "WHERE urlCount.url.urlTx IN :urls " +
        "AND et.referEventTypeDs =:eventType " +
        "AND urlCount.updateTimeStamp >= function('ADD_MONTH', CURRENT_DATE, :month)")
```